# Show base64 PDF on iOS Safari using java-script

Tags: javascript, safari, base64

I have a PDF that i want to download/show based on a base64 string from an API call, however, it does not work on iOS. Any ideas?

The following code works on a desktop browser:

```
const data = await $axios.get(this.downloadUrl);
const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = "data:application/pdf;base64," + data.data.data;
downloadLink.download = this.filename;
downloadLink.click();
```